# Mapping objects in an array with loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I've got an array with some objects :

```
var myArray = [{
    'id': 'first',
    'value': 'firstValue'
}, {
    'id': 'second',
    'value': 'secondValue'
}, {
    'id': 'third',
    'value': 'thirdValue'
}, etc.];
```

I'm trying to add values with 'for' loop so that I have something like this :

```
var myArray = [{
    'id': 'first',
    'value': 'firstValue',
    'inc' : 1
}, {
    'id': 'second',
    'value': 'secondValue'
    'inc' : 2
}, {
    'id': 'third',
    'value': 'thirdValue'
    'inc' : 3
}, etc.];
```

I have tried to do it with mapping

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    myArray = myArray.map(function(obj) {
        obj.inc = i;
        return obj;
    });
}
```

But all my 'inc' values in array are the same (all equal to 49, one less of 'myArray.length'). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add properties to object directly, using `map` will cause an error as it's not defined on objects. Try this:

```
myArray.forEach(function(o, i) { // for each object o in the array
  o.inc = i + 1;                 // add a property inc equal to it's index + 1
});
```

Or in recent ECMAScripts just:

```
myArray.forEach((o, i) => o.inc = i + 1);
```

Comment: That did it for me, thank you! Strangely, WebStorm highlights the ECMAScripts expression red, but it works nevertheless

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the outer `for` loop, you just need to utilize the `index` argument `map` supplies:

```
var withIncAdded = myArray.map(function(obj, index) {
    obj.inc = index + 1;
    return obj;
});
```

[`Array.map` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters)

Comment: He's mutating the array qo just `forEach` will do!

Answer (score 2):

`Array#map` is a loop itself so it's not that wise idea to drop it inside another `for` loop.

Anyways I would suggest you to use `Array#forEach`. It works faster than `Array#map` because it doesn't return a new array.

```js
var myArray = [{'id':'first','value':'firstValue'},{'id':'second','value':'secondValue'},{'id':'third','value':'thirdValue'}]
    myArray.forEach((v,i) => v.inc = i+1);

    console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Like with @ibrahim mahrir, WebStorm highlights it red but manages to run it anyways, so I guess it will do too